# Can't add New Events "From Template" after upgrade to 4.6

Tags: civievent

After upgrading from Civi 4.4 to 4.6.7, we no longer have the capability to add a new event from an existing event template.

To replicate:

1) Visit Events > New Event
2) On the "New Event" page, select an existing template in the "From Template" box

Expected behavior:

After OK'ing a "you're navigating away" browser dialog, the "New Event" page reloads with most fields completed based on our existing template.

Current behavior:

Nothing happens.  Nothing shows up on the browser's JS console.

I tried changing themes to make sure it's nothing in our theme's JS.

Any suggestions for further troubleshooting?

Thanks!

Comment: (BTW, I did try the suggestion of creating new templates to see if they are also unusable: same results.  Selecting new templates created for this purpose did NOT populate the New Event form.  Very open to other suggestions.  And thanks, @petednz-fuzion!)

Answer (score 2):

Other suggestions that might help add clues:

1. confirm if you have similar problems with creating Events from templates you created post upgrade. Ie is this problem only relating to templates that existed prior to the upgrade
2. if any of your clicks result in a pop up box, instead of clicking, right click, open in 'new tab' then continue, that way you should see errors/backtrace (assuming you have this turned on from Admin > System Settings)
3. compare behaviour between your system and the civicrm demo site.